# Close and restart excel at arbitrary point in running a macro?

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, solver

Suppose there is a marcro `example_code` in a excel 2016 file: `example_excel.xlsm` which has a lot of code but does not create external files (all the calculations are performed in`example_excel.xlsm`.

I was curious as to whether there is a way to:

1. Break/pause the running code at an arbitrary moment.
2. Manually add the next line in code that: Runs/calls a function/sub that:
3. Saves the complete `example_excel.xlsm` state (including the sheet and cell that are activated and selected, as well as the variables/code-running environment),
4. Close it at any arbitrary point in the code, and
5. Re-open the excel
6. Continue running code `example_code` from where you left off,
7. After removing the inserted line that saves the excel state,
8. either instantly
9. or after clicking 1 button/running 1 macro?

Since I have a complex code that runs in instances of 2 hours while running 
multiple programmed setups of the "solver" and while troubleshooting a specific state of solver, I am waiting an hour before that state occurs/is triggered.

Now the easy fix would be to look up all the parameters, sheet- and cell-states that are present in that state, store them in a separate sheet, and then re-initialize them. But that does not allow for flexibility in trouble shooting if another state needs to be evaluated, nor is it convenient when using the .ie object that has an infinite loop inside it , e.g. parent has a child that has an item that is the child's parent again (I thought this existed, though I am not sure).

The difficult answer is; rewrite/refactor your code so that it becomes less complex and more insightful. That I definitely need to do, nevertheless even when that is done, a generalized tool to save the states while running is at least for me, desirable.

**Attempts so far:** [in edit-will elaborate.]
My main starting point difficulty is that I do not know how to run through all the parameters/variables if the list of parameters is unknown.

So far, since the original problem consisted of multiple runs of 2 hours, I have written a code that automatically copies all the sheets, and all the modules and forms from the current excel to a different excel. That allows for saving everything but the variables inside the code, nor the sheet and cell activation.

Since that code does specifically not apply to an arbitrary time during a running code, nor copy the variables used by excel, I consider that code off-topic, unless requested otherwise.

I feel like I am looking for a very narrowed down solution approach, so suggestions for looking into different/broader options to solve the problem are welcome!

Comment: No, there is no built-in way for that. VBA can not store any information between runs. Your only options is to write your macro in a way that it writes all relevant information to a sheet and reads it back when you need to resume run.

Comment: Thank you @MátéJuhász, I assume I do not know enough about proper programming etiquette to understand why this option would not be very effective to have in excel, but perhaps there is a different reason. Perhaps some creative-work arounds are be suggested.

Comment: "Perhaps some creative-work arounds are be suggested" - what exactly do you expect? VBA is basically a scripting language, included in Excel to automate tasks, and not intended to be anything more. It has it's limitation regarding performance and functionality, of course you can work around them, but that takes you write a lot of code.

Comment: What I expect, is that I am not the only one who has tried to tackle this problem in stead of working around it. I expect there is a possibility that someone solved it for a less difficult scenario (one could for example, without the solver, write a code that indeed automatically stores the state.)  I expect that, if that person/some of those persons share that information, there is a possibility that that different perspective allows me to solve my problem. I will post my my solution to the more difficult/different problem if I find one. I expect it can/could benefit someone else after me.

Comment: I've not yet done anything like this, hope somebody else will share it. Anyway it will need to follow this approach: write to spreadsheet ALL variables either regularly or each time it changes, then at resume read them back and continue macro. I'm sure it'll complicate code a lot.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thank you for the suggestion, it made me realize the problem is too constraint, indeed storing the variables regularly or each time it changes, makes the code run a lot more slow, and a lot more complicated. Whereas being able to manually run 1 line before closing should be time efficient. (It would allow to store only that state, and not the continuous states). So I will add that option.